# How to flat a list of lists and ensure the output result distributed evenly in python?

Tags: python

Given there is a list if lists like the below.

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [6, 8, 9, 10],
  [11]
]
```

I hope that I can flatten the list and the output should be `[1, 4, 6, 11, 2, 5, 8, 3, 9, 10]`. How to implement this in Python?

Comment: @Multihunter No, there is an additional requirement in my question.

Comment: I see. You want to interleave. Your question only states flattening. My apologies. Do you contest the other duplicate as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zip_longest` function from the `itertools` module to combine these lists, and just throw away the `None` fillvalues

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list_of_lists = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 8, 9, 10],
    [11]
    ]

flat_list = []
for tup in zip_longest(*list_of_lists, fillvalue=None):
    for e in tup:
        if e is not None:
            flat_list.append(e)

print(flat_list)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
flat_list = [e for tup in zip_longest(*list_of_lists) for e in tup if e is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5],
[6, 8, 9, 10],
[11]]
from itertools import zip_longest
[i for lst in zip_longest(*data) for i in lst if i is not None]
```

or a more complex way:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from functools import reduce
list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, zip_longest(*data))))
```

or

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + tuple(i for i in y if i is not None), zip_longest(*data))
```

if it is ok, I can explain it

Answer (score 0):

```py
tree = [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5],
        [6, 8, 9, 10],
        [11]]

stump = [
    sublist[i]
    for i in range(max(map(len, tree)))
    for sublist in tree if len(sublist) > i
    ]

print(stump) #[1, 4, 6, 11, 2, 5, 8, 3, 9, 10]
```